# Movie with kid crawling on the ceiling

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

It was a movie I saw as a kid and like the kid I think was crawling on the ceiling and it was horror. I asked my dad and he said it involved crows, but nothing is pulling up.

Comment: There was a scene in *Trainspotting* like that, but it's not on-topic.

Comment: When were you a kid?  How many years ago?  Was this on TV?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: There’s also hotel Transylvania and the Addams family (the newest animated one) that had scenes like that.

Answer (score 4):

That's the 2007 film, [*The Messengers*](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_messengers).

> When the Solomons trade in the craziness of big-city life for the quiet of a North Dakota farm, little do they expect the nightmare that follows. Soon after arriving, teenage Jess (Kristen Stewart) and her younger brother see terrifying apparitions and endure attacks from a supernatural source. Jess must warn her disbelieving family before it is too late to save them.

It involves crow attacks, and ghosts that only Ben, the younger brother, sees at first, including a child that crawls across the ceiling.

It's the crows that you mentioned that made me think of this one, then a search for the title and "ceiling" found a few people referencing the child moving across the ceiling. It's not a great film, but decent. The sequel (actually a prequel) was a bit worse.

### Ben watching the child crawl up the wall and across the ceiling

FWIW, the bit that got me and my wife to watch (and might have stuck out in the minds of others), was a scene where the mother was fluffing the sheets, and a pair of ghostly legs are briefly visible in the trailer.